Vector bundle associated to the universal cover $\mathbb{R}\to S^1$
It's a well known fact that, given a principal $G$-bundle (where $G$ is a Lie subgroup of $\text{GL}(r,\mathbb{R})$)
$$\pi_P:P\to X$$
there is an associated vector bundle
$$\pi_E:E(P):=(P\times \mathbb{R}^r)/G\to X,\ \ \ [p,v]\mapsto\pi_P(p),$$
whom fiber is $\mathbb{R}^r$. I'm wondering what do we get, if we take as principal bundle the $\mathbb{Z}$-bundle given by the universal cover
$$p:\mathbb{R}\to S^1,\ \ \ x\mapsto e^{2\pi ix}.$$
(I'm considering $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subgroup of $\text{GL}(1,\mathbb{R})$ through the representation $z\in \mathbb{Z}\mapsto e^z$). Clearly the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on the total space $\mathbb{R}$ is given by the sum.
We should get this
$$(\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}\to S^1,\ \ \ [x,y]\mapsto p(x),$$
where in the domain we are quotienting with respect to the action $(x,y)a:=(x+a,e^a y)$.
I'd like to know if there is any intuitive way of thinking about the above vector bundle. Specifically I'd like to know which $2$-dimensional manifold is $(\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}$.

This is (isomorphic to) the trivial $\mathbb{R}$ bundle over $S^1$: it is the pullback from $(S^1 \times [0,1] \times \mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}$ via $(\mathrm{id}, 1)$ where $\mathbb{Z}$ acts by $(x, s, a) \mapsto (x + a, s , e^{as}y)$, and therefore isomorphic to the pullback via $(\mathrm{id}, 0)$.
More generally, an $F$-bundle over $S^1$ is the mapping torus of a map $g: F \to F$ (by realizing it as $(\mathbb{R} \times F)/(x, f) \sim (x + 1, g(f))$), and changing $g$ up to homotopy keeps the bundle isomorphic. Since $\mathrm{GL}(1, \mathbb{R})$ has two components, there are at most two rank $1$ vector bundles over $S^1$ up to isomorphism (in fact exactly two but you need a separate argument to see that they are non-isomorphic).
